# Nodejs and Typescript Cannot find module or process

Tags: node.js, typescript, process

I'm new to Typescript. Today I tried to set up a project with Nodejs & typescript. But in my every file I'm getting `Cannot find module ''` & `Cannot find name process` errors. I tried everything that I can find but none of them got success. Please help me to remove these errors.

[image]

[image] [image] [image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the necessary types in `package.json` and did you run `npm install`?

Comment: check this link out <br>
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35122246/typescript-cannot-find-module-with-valid-typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35122246/typescript-cannot-find-module-with-valid-typings)

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig, try changing module to ES6 or ES2015

```
"module": "ES2015"

OR

"module": "ES6"
```

Also, confirm if npm install was complete. If not, for surely, rerun it again.